# Where is Azure Let's Encrypt extension's GUI?

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt, extension, azure-web-apps

I'm following this tutorial https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/20047 . I created the principal, configured all the Web App Settings variables described (I even configured the email address and the domain name as an extra, since I don't see the GUI anywhere). The extension seems to install without an error. I restarted the web app, and I even see the running WebJob by the extension.

I cannot figure out where to get to the configuration interface of the extension though. The tutorial above says

> After the restart, click the triangle Launch button that replaced the extension's install button."

The extension installation UI seemingly changed since the article. I don't see any triangle. There's a browse button, but that's disabled.

The github wiki doesn't mention anything either, like it was straight forward: https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension/wiki/How-to-install#configure-the-site-extension

> The first page of the site contains the following...

What site? I tried to navigate to `/letsencrypt/` of my webapp but it doesn't exist.

I'm not presented with any dialog when I install the extension.

[image]

[image]

If I look at the installed site extensions from the Kudu SCM site, under the installed section I see the two installed extension properly, but oddly I can install them again, and I suspect that the "+" button should turn to a triangle (as the original tutorial suggests)? If I install it again supposedly it installs itself successfully again, but I still don't know where to finish the GUI part of the config.

In the WebApp Settings I didn't specify `letsencrypt:ServicePlanResourceGroupName` because I don't know hwta it is and we have only one service plan.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI is at https://[your-webapp].scm.azurewebsites.net/letsencrypt

If it doesn't exists try to restart the SCM site. I should exits. Otherwise provide the logs from D:\home\LogFiles\Transform

Comment: I thought I tried that URL before. I see the website now. Battling with the right TenantID.

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem